# What's the best way to preserve a model across android configuration changes?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application, I have a fragment which renders a model object fetched from the server. The model class implements `Parcelable` so when the device is rotated, I save the model in `onSaveInstanceState()` and then I load the model in `onCreate()`. If the `savedInstanceState` bundle does not contain the model in `onCreate()`, I make the network request again.

My question is: Is it better to preserve the state of the model by having it implement `Parcelable` and saving it in `onSaveInstanceState()` **OR** is it better to simply set the `Fragment`'s `setRetainInstanceState(true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion setInstanceState should be used only in special cases, while onSaveInstanceState() should be used as standard approach to keep fragment's state. This is common way for keeping state of all Android's components.
Keeping fragment in memory can  lead to situations like strange views behavior and memory leaks.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean and it is based on those experiences that I believe that the simplest solution is just to Parcel the model in `onSaveInsatnceState`. However, in much of the source code i've seen, ``setRetainInstanceState` seems to be the preferred method. I'm going to wait for a few more answers

Comment: I totally agree with @piotrpo. You can retain your model in the state, and get it back in onCreate(). This is the only way to get your data when your app goes to background, is killed by the system to get memory and brought to foreground by the user lately.

Comment: @W.K.S `saveinstanceState` is easy - much easier than to implement real data serialization / deserialization. I think that this is the main reason.

Answer (score 0):

The [API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) recommends using a retained headless data fragment.

Comment: I've read the guide. The part that confuses me is why keep a headless fragment in an Activity? Why not just put the model in the Fragment along with the UI and setReainInstanceState(true)

Comment: Because then you retain the UI and not just the data. If, for example, your portrait and landscape have different UI, you would not want to retain it.